# Tick label displayed when clicking on graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, click, axis-labels

When one clicks on a Matplotlib graph, the coordinates of the current point are normally displayed.

However, when tick labels are set (with `pyplot.yticks()`, for example) before a `pyplot.plot()`, nothing is displayed for the label coordinate (Matplotlib displays an empty `y =`, in this case).  Is there a simple way of having Matplotlib display the tick labels instead (ideally without using the event handling machinery, which can probably do this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found it:

```
pyplot.gca().fmt_ydata = lambda y: label[int(round(y))]
```

where `label` maps ordinates to tick labels (`pyplot.gca()` can be replaced by the axes of interest, if needed).

In fact, the `fmt_ydata()` function of the axes is called by Matplotlib when clicking in them.